# running JavaScript on a file:/// page (opened with Chrome on Windows 7)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, windows-7, iframe, local

**the idea:**
I'd like to make a very lightweight alternative to Windows Explorer for sorting and viewing my pictures, and the best approach (if it is possible) that I can think of is using javascript and jQuery to parse the html that is generated when I enter a file:/// url into Chrome.

**possible approach:**
The only way I can think to do this is to have a html page linking to my script, with an iframe containing the file:/// generated page, then accessing the list of files from there.

**EDIT** *example of the possible approach. `explore.js` would have a script that accesses DOM elements inside `myFrame` and generates a custom view of the directory*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="explore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>My Explorer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="myFrame" src="file:///c:/my/pics/directory"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**questons:**
I've played around a *little* with no success - is it possible to access an iframe in this way (and how would this be approached)? Is there another approach that would give me something with similar simplicity, customizability and portability?

Comment: To access an iframe in what way?

Comment: @Tomalak to access an iframe's DOM from a script in the parent page. I'll add an example to the question.

Comment: I think chrome doesn't like local javascript files. It's fine with HTML but it refuses to load local javascript files.

Comment: @Jonas that's definitely incorrect - I've had Crome run plenty of local javascript files (it would be useless for web development if it didn't). The main problem here is that Chrome seems to have a blanket ban on accessing file:/// iframe documents, regardless whether the parent page is local or remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through some explorations I've found that Chrome's current behaviour is not to allow access to the DOM of an iframe from the local domain, regardless of whether the parent frame is local. I'll have to look at another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers won't let you display local files in an `iframe` for security reasons (though this may be waived if the parent document is local, too).

You can absolutely [access the `iframe`'s DOM](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/299.htm).

Have you considered running a webserver on your computer and using server-side scripting instead?

Comment: Chrome doesn't seem to have a problem with local files in an iframe (at least one in a local html document). What sort of DOM methods (or jQuery) would give access to the iframe?

Comment: @DrMonkey: Follow the link I gave you. The `iframe` node has a `document` child that you can use just like the parent's `document`.

Comment: I have considered running a web server as a fallback option, but essentially I'm looking for something very lightweight that I could carry around on a USB stick and use on different systems with minimal fuss.

Comment: @DrMonkey: Sounds like that's going to be some compiled application, tbh. :) If you want simple, why not use Windows Explorer that's on all the different Windows systems already?

Comment: @Tomalak: basically it doesn't do what I want it to, and once I get the iframe thing sorted out it will be quite easy to throw something together in js that suits my purpose. The stuff in the link doesn't seem to be working in Chrome (the post is about IE) - it could just be that the iframe's document isn't loading before I run the script, but I'll have to have a crack at that a bit later on as I've been called away.

Comment: @DrMonkey: Yes, you will of course have to wait for the DOM to load before you attempt to manipulate it.